# How to make a boxplot with the 5 points summary ready with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

**Dummy data**

```
d = data.frame(type=LETTERS[1:3], ymin=c(1,1.1,2), lower=c(1.5,1.5,4), middle=c(1.6,1.8,4.5), upper=c(2,2.1,7), ymax=c(2.5, 2.6, 10))
  type ymin lower middle upper ymax
1    A  1.0   1.5    1.6   2.0  2.5
2    B  1.1   1.5    1.8   2.1  2.6
3    C  2.0   4.0    4.5   7.0 10.0
```

**Goal**

I would like to make a boxplot with `ggplot2` with the kind of data showed above, where I already 5 the positions of the 5 points for the boxplot. In the above case, there must have 3 different boxes.

**What I tried**

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=type, y=middle)) + stat_summary(geom="boxplot", list(ymin=ymin, lower=lower, middle=middle, upper=upper, ymax=ymax))
```

and

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=type, y=middle)) + geom_boxplot(ymin=ymin, lower=lower, middle=middle, upper=upper, ymax=ymax)
```

but both fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=type)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(ymin=ymin, lower=lower, middle=middle, upper=upper, ymax=ymax),
                 stat = "identity")
```

[image]

You were close with the second try, but you needed to put the arguments in an `aes`, and to add `stat = "identity"` to the boxplot (so that it wouldn't try to apply the summarizing itself).